# How do I split records in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I'm trying to split records in python using split function but unable to achieve the actual outcome.

Here is the contents of my `.txt` file in below:

```
10000  {(10000,200,300,A),(10000,200,300,B)},{(10000,200,300,C),(10000,200,300,D)}
10001  {(10001,200,300,E),(10001,200,300,F)},{(10001,200,300,G),(10001,200,300,H)}
```

Here is the desired output:

```
10000  10000,200,300,A
10000  10000,200,300,B
10000  10000,200,300,C
10000  10000,200,300,D
10001  10001,200,300,E
10001  10001,200,300,F
10001  10001,200,300,G
10001  10001,200,300,H
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be able to parse your text file first

Comment: Do you want to store the output in a text file?

Comment: i want to store it in excel file

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to get the desired result, it only requires the `sub` and `findall` methods from the `re` package to work.

```
from re import sub, findall

string = """
  10000 {(10000,200,300,A),(10000,200,300,B)},{(10000,200,300,C),(10000,200,300,D)}
  10001 {(10001,200,300,E),(10001,200,300,F)},{(10001,200,300,G),(10001,200,300,H)}
"""

# our results go here
results = []

# loop through each line in the string
for line in string.split("\n"):
  # get rid of leading and trailing whitespace
  line = line.strip()
  # ignore empty lines
  if len(line) > 0:
    # get the line's id
    id = line.split("{")[0].strip()
    # get all values wrapped in parenthesis
    for match in findall("(\(.*?\))", string):
      # add the string to the results list
      results.append("{} {}".format(id, sub(r"\{|\}", "", match)))

# display the results
print(results)
```

Here is the same code in function form:

```
from re import sub, findall

def get_records(string):
  # our results go here
  results = []
  # loop through each line in the string
  for line in string.split("\n"):
    # get rid of leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # ignore empty lines
    if len(line) > 0:
      # get the line's id
      id = line.split("{")[0].strip()
      # get all values wrapped in parenthesis
      for match in findall("(\(.*?\))", string):
        # add the string to the results list
        results.append("{} {}".format(id, sub(r"\{|\}", "", match)))
  # return the results list
  return results
```

You would then use the function, like this:

```
# print the results
print(get_records("""
  10000 {(10000,200,300,A),(10000,200,300,B)},{(10000,200,300,C),(10000,200,300,D)}
  10001 {(10001,200,300,E),(10001,200,300,F)},{(10001,200,300,G),(10001,200,300,H)}
"""))
```

Good luck.

Comment: @BeekashMohanty You're very welcome, if the answer worked, don't forget to mark it as accepted using the green tick beneath the down arrow.

Comment: You could probably do `if line:` instead of `if len(line) > 0:`.

Comment: @RoadRunner doesn't that just check for the line's existence / *"truthiness"*?

Comment: @LogicalBranch Yes. If a line not empty -> true, otherwise -> false.